# Invalid Host header error in my react app on server

Tags: reactjs, nginx, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, nginx-config

I have a server with its own nginx settings. I have a react application deployed there along with a django (drf) backend. They are both wrapped in docker as well as nginx itself. Everything runs and works. But when I click on the link I get an "Invalid Host header" error.
Could you please tell me what could be the problem.

nginx settings:

```
upstream react-app {
    server react-app:3000;
}

upstream app {
    server core:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <my_server_name>;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://react-app;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://app/api/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://app/admin/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias <folder>/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias <folder>/media/;
    }
}
```

my react package.json:

```
{
  "name": "lookee-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://<my_server_name>",
  "dependencies": {
    "dependencies",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "my_dependencies",
  },
  "proxy": "http://<my_server_name>/"
}
```

Instead of the proxy parameter in package.json, I tried to insert the container names in the format "http://core/". I tried to remove this parameter altogether. It didn't work. But when I removed this parameter, the server would get an error when I enabled javascript support.